# SAS - Format proc report grand total with percent

Tags: excel, sas, ods

I try to make a proc report with formula with **ODS EXCEL**. I use SAS 9.4.

I have coded this.
For each person, I would like to have the number of actions and a ratio.
But, I can't apply percent format to the grand Total.

```
proc report data=_TEMP.STATS(where=(  compress(tranwrd(LIB_BUR,"'",''))="&f_equ.")) headline headskip;
        column  PERSO_ID  nb_err nb_ok tx_maj;
        define PERSO_ID / GROUP 'Conseiller';
        define nb_err / SUM 'Nb Maj non effectuées';
        define nb_ok / SUM 'Nb Maj effectuées';
        define tx_maj / computed display 'Tx maj effectuées' format=percent4.2
            style(column)={tagattr="format:0.00% formula:RC[-1]/(RC[-1]+RC[-2])"};
        rbreak after /summarize style=[BACKGROUND=cxECEDEC];
    quit;
```

[Results KO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaGtN.png)

How can I format the Total with percent.

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What release of 9.4 do you have?

This `REPORT` code does correctly compute the %OK of the totals (per the tagattr specified format and formula):

```
data have;
  length person $20;
  input person error_count ok_count; datalines;
BOSSUVE    9   12
BRALAU    13  160
DURIEUJE   1   52
MARECAUU  39  116
run;

ods excel file='C:\Temp\demo.xlsx';

proc report data=have;
  columns person error_count ok_count ok_pct;

  define ok_pct / computed 'Ok %'
    width = 21
    style(column) = {
      width = 1.5cm
      tagattr = "
        format:0.00%
        formula:RC[-1]/(RC[-1]+RC[-2])
      "
    }
  ;

  compute after;
    person = 'Total';
  endcomp;

  rbreak after / summarize;
run;

ods excel close;
```

[image]